# Date Params minimum date is today in URL

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, date, datepicker

I have a booking application, and I'm passing Date params to URL from Bootstrap Date-picker in Ruby rails application, it also detects and handles manual entry for invalid dates  on URL.

However, in URL user can change Date params to date in past and proceed to next step. As I set minimum date is to day in date-picker, I want to prevent this action also  I need to detect  "valid" dates that are in the past as currently it allows user to carry on booking rather than re-directing ( as detected when user inputs invalid date  ie 55/09/2017)

It is works fine with JavaScript but not with the pages with Ajax. 
Is there anyway to fix this ? or anyway to handle this without using JavaScript?

note : - I'm passing a Date value dynamically  to the next page and  it has no relationship with data in Database.

UPDATE :  The working codes

```
module DateCheckerHelper
  def min_date_validation
    date =Date.strptime(params[:outbound],"%d/%m/%Y") 
    date <  Date.today
  end
end


class MyController < ApplicationController

  include DateCheckerHelper

  def show
    if min_date_validation
      redirect_to root_path
    end  
  end
end
```

Handle Argument Error (invalid Date)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from ArgumentError, :with => :argument_error_rescue
  private

  def argument_error_rescue
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you using Ajax exclusively to handle date entry or are you using a rails controller to handle the request?

Comment: @ScottMonceaux I'm using rails controller to handle invalid date Argument Error

Comment: I use dates a lot and had to come up with a solution. I'll post what I use and hopefully it will help.

Comment: Why are you putting params[:outbound] in the form? params is nil until submit the form. Also by placing a rescue on argument errors, it won't allow you to see what exactly the error is. Comment out the rescue in your application controller until you figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I use this set up a lot for handling dates via params:

EDIT AGAIN: updated to reflect use of helper and datepicker and use redirect if date earlier than today.

```
class SomeClass < ApplicationController
  def method
    if !date_valid?(params[:date])
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "What were you thinking?"
    end
  end
end

module SomeHelper
  def date_valid?(date)
    date_array = date.split("/").map(&:to_i)
    Date.valid_date?(*date_array) && Date.new(date) > Date.today
  end
end
```

Comment: My code is  bit similar to this and I have use redirection to handle invalid date Argument Error . If I manually enter invalid date in URL it will call the action and works fine.However, If I enter date is past in the URL and allows me to go to next page as it not invalid date. therefore, I looking for a  method to handle past date in URL . The code below is written to check min Date in Application controller
 def date_checker
    date = Date.new(params[:outbound])
    if date < Date.today
      redirect_to root_path
    end  
 end

Comment: I still getting same response.However, I believe I place them in wrong controller . I define it as a helper method in Application controller and calling them in before_action in other controllers. any suggestions ? thank you.

Comment: Thank you for  that. However  its redirect to  root_path even its valid date or past date. I have created a module helper named "date_checker_helper" and call it from controllers. I hope I did it right

Comment: @roshiend edit you question and add the current code you are using and we can look at what ya got.

Comment: @roshiend add a '?' to the end of date_valid so it will ask if the return is true or false. I edited mine cuz I forgot to add it in the controller. Without the question mark, just asks if the method is nil. That should fix you up.

Comment: still the same. my codes are must be wrong in somewhere else. I appreciate your help. thank you.

Comment: @roshiend does it work correctly when you put in a valid date?

Comment: yes its works fine . #date = Date.parse(params[:outbound]).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")                     #today = Date.today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") works too but it count as an invalid date (dates like 01/mm/yyyy. (dates below 10)) . but above code with strptime will fixed the issue. now its validate dates in past and redirect also  dates below 10 validate properly.